# Vue - Cannot use import statement outside a module

Tags: vue.js

I´m trying to create a form. This form have a package.json with vue, axios and sweetalert.

```json
"dependencies": {
  "axios": "^0.19.0",
  "vue": "^2.6.10",
  "vue-sweetalert2": "^2.1.1"
}
```

The JS is

```html
<script>
  import Vue from 'vue';
  import VueSweetalert2 from 'vue-sweetalert2';
  import VueAxios from 'vue-axios';
  import axios from 'axios';
  import 'sweetalert2/dist/sweetalert2.min.css';
  Vue.use(VueSweetalert2, VueAxios, axios);
  var app = new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    methods: {
      guardar: function () {
        axios
          .get('ENDPONT')
          .then(response => {
            console.log(response);
            Vue.swal('Hello Vue world!!!');

          })
          .catch(function (error) {
            console.log(error);
            Vue.swal('Hello Vue world!!!');
          });
      }
    }
  });
</script>
```

The error is simple: Return 'Cannot use import statement outside a module'. I suppose that import is wrong, but im new in Vue and don't know what is the right way.

Answer (score 5):

You're trying to use an import statement in a normal script tag, you can only do that with `type="module"` but I suspect you will run into many other issues if you continue down this path as many libraries are not built for use with ESM modules yet.

You'll be better off generating a project with https://cli.vuejs.org/ which will create a good starting base and compile your code and put it in a `/build` folder for you to deploy to your web hosting.

Answer (score 0):

Hello encountered the same issue in laravel 9 with vue3 js and vite

- the solution you have to configure your .env
  because when you run => npm run build, it create the build folder where your js, images , css will be compile, those files will be used in your App
- Go in .env and Add this code: ASSET_URL=http://localhost/public
- Now if you run build, all object will be prefix by //localhost/public
  =>Ex. ***http://localhost/public/build/js/app1332527.js***

Answer (score -1):

```
require('__path_to_vue.js__')
```

If you intend to use it outside module

Answer (score -2):

I removed ***defer*** from

```
<script src="{{ asset('js/app.js') }}" defer></script>
```

and it worked perfectly