# vue-js / asp.net core - ERROR : did you register the component correctly?

Tags: asp.net-core, vuejs2, vue-component

I'm rather new to vue.js, so forgive me if it this is an uts-question :-)

The project is a asp.net core project were we integrated vue.js as a means to enrich the user-experience. In the past we used jQueru/jQueryUI. Given the ease of working we switched to vue.

I want to use this nice color picker component I downloaded from here https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue-swatches#install

I included the .js and .css file to my page and in my script I have already added successfully other components but the same method does not work for this one.

```
<div id="appointmentsvue" class="row">

    <select v-model="selectedCareprovider" v-on:change="onSelectedCareproviderChanged" class="form-control">
        <option v-for="careprovider in careproviders" v-bind:value="careprovider">
            {{careprovider.FullName}}
        </option>
    </select>
    <v-colorpicker v-model="selectedColor"></v-colorpicker>
</div>

<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue/dist/vue.js"></script>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="/lib/vue-select/vue-select.css" />
<script src="/lib/vue-select/vue-select.js"></script>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="/lib/vue-swatches/vue-swatches.min.css" />
<script src="/lib/vue-swatches/vue-swatches.min.js"></script>

<script>
    let appointmentsvue = new Vue({
        el: '#appointmentsvue',
        components: {
            'v-colorpicker': VueSwatches.VueSwatches // https://saintplay.github.io/vue-swatches/
        },
        data: {
            selectedColor: '#AABBCC',
            careproviders: [],
            selectedCareprovider: {},
        },
        methods: {
            onSelectedCareproviderChanged: function () {
            },
            updateCareprovider: function () {
            },
        }
    });
</script>
```

I get this error after loading the page.

> [Vue warn]: Unknown custom element:  - did you register
>   the component correctly? For recursive components, make sure to
>   provide the "name" option.

Any suggestions ?

Comment: did you create your project using `vue-cli`?

Comment: No it is asp.net core project where I added vue.js as means to improve the ui.

Comment: I see. Well the only reason I ask is it might be a configuration issue with vue. I referenced this [article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58130390/vue-cannot-use-import-statement-outside-a-module). Not sure if it can help you any...

Comment: Thx for the hint but no solution for me to be found there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On the git-pages of this component I got a solution :

https://github.com/saintplay/vue-swatches/issues/37

A solution I used for other components too.

Answer (score 0):

I did not found a true answer that allowed me just to add the javascript files to my html pages and use those components.

I found a working solution by introducing webpack, usefull resources :

[webpack beginners guide](https://webpack.js.org/guides/getting-started/#basic-setup)
[vuejs and webpack from scratch](https://itnext.io/vuejs-and-webpack-4-from-scratch-part-1-94c9c28a534a)
[webpack and aps.net core](https://medium.com/@lars.willemsens/managing-asp-net-core-mvc-front-end-dependencies-with-npm-and-webpack-part-1-1f6a8b8a1289)